# How to play a mp4 video with Apache Royale?

Tags: html5-video, videodisplay, apache-royale

All is in the title.
I didn't see a `VideoDisplay` in SDK. So must I wrap a javascript videoplayer (https://royale.apache.org/using-external-javascript-libraries-in-apache-royale/) or is there other method ?

Is there a way to specify compiler/or API that we want a specific HTML element (like `<video>`) ?

Regards